# How to get single Bounding rectangle around multiple shapes in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I have multiple shapes on canvas. I need to generate a bounding rectangle around all the selected shapes without altering their existing positions, and I should be able to resize and rotate them as well.

When I resize the whole group, the scale should apply to all the shapes inside. Right now, I'm able to select multiple shapes and to resize them at a time as well, but I don't have a common bounding rectangle for those selected shapes.

I'm a beginner for WPF. Kindly post any ideas regarding the issue.

Comment: To clarify: do you want to know how to draw the rectange, as Erno's answer addresses, or do you want to know how to calculate the bounding rectangle?

Comment: Hi gorky thanks for considering,I want to draw the bounding rectangle around the shapes and should be able to resize it where the scale is applies to inside shapes as well, just like grouping in MS Powerpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx).

[Or an alternative implementation](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/wpf-overlays-or-better-adorner/)

Comment: Thankyou very much for the reply Erno. Actually, Im using adorners for the resizing the individual shapes. But Im not able to arrange a common bounding rectangle around the selected shapes without using another canvas or panel. Even if I did that, im not getting scaling(changing size along with group) of shapes with re-size of bounding rectangle.
Again thank you very much for considering,kindly look into the issue again.

Revanth M.

Answer (score 0):

I do have similar Question here.

[how to get a boundingbox for multiple items in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115710/how-to-get-a-boundingbox-for-multiple-items-in-wpf)

[get XY of object in wpf for this situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213190/get-xy-of-object-in-wpf-for-this-situation)

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/830/2011/5/25

The solution works, but not for rotation.